# Проблемы с передачей данных между activity

Tags: android, java

Значит так, задача такая: с одного активити, переключиться на другой, и передать некоторые данные предыдущему. Такой код получился в итоге:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (arg0 == button1) {
        int year = cal.getYear();
        int month = cal.getMonth();
        int day = cal.getDayOfMonth();
        int hour = timer.getCurrentHour();
        int minute = timer.getCurrentMinute();
        boolean calenda = true;

        Intent z = new Intent(this, Newnote.class);
        z.putExtra("year", year);
        z.putExtra("month", month);
        z.putExtra("day", day);
        z.putExtra("hour", hour);
        z.putExtra("minute", minute);
        z.putExtra("calenda", calenda);

        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что эти данные не передаются. Как я понял, мне обязательно нужно открыть активность, чтобы все эти параметры передались ей. Я бы рад, но тогда получится, что в приложении открыто 2 Activity.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то передать данные не открывая активити **или же** как при открытии второй активити, закрыть первую?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам необходимо из **активити А** запустить **активити Б** методом **startActivityForResult()**
Затем в **активности Б** вызвать метод **setResult()**, куда и передать объект **Intent** с данными.

Затем в **активити А** переопределить метод **onActivityResult()**, в котором вы извелечете полученные данные. Будьте внимательны, поскольку если в **активности А** у вас есть диалоговые окна, то при их закрытии метод **onActivityResult()** так же будет срабатывать.

На счет двух активити: когда вы из первой откроете вторую, в первой сработает метод **onPause()**

Comment: можно и с 2я, через интент, тогда первое надо будет финишировать все время...

Comment: да способов много, например тот же BroadcastReciever

Comment: угу, или в одном активити писать в бд, а в другом читать =) или проперти))

Comment: :DDD поржал

Comment: @Роман - вы описываете способ возврата результата из активити - это немного не то что ожидает испытуемый :)

Comment: @Barmaley - хм, судя по тому, что ответ принят - видимо ожидался именно он :)