# Передача события активити Б в активити А

Tags: java, android, activity, button, события

Столкнулся с необходимостью одного обработчика для кнопок с разных активити, при этом не закрывая второе активити. Это возможно? Просто я один из "все в одном файле", поэтому обработчик привязан к экземплярам и методам класса с первой кнопкой и никак не связан со второй. 
Например в плеерах есть активити с нижним баром кнопок и активити с полным описанием трека и такими же кнопками. 
Кроме варианта с передачей экземпляров первого активити во второе, при его создании ничего придумать не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каждый момент времени работает только одно активити, то, которое видимо на экране. Все остальные в фоне (или вовсе уничтожены) и код в них в любом случае  не выполняется (в Android 7 ввели режим многооконности, но и там выполняется код только видимых на экране активити).

Вы можете написать свой отдельный класс-слушатель кликов ([реализацию интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/259662/177345) `OnClickListener`)и подключать его в разных активити, но на практике такой подход обычно трудно реализуем и несет больше костылей, чем профита.
В плеерах с двумя рядами кнопок (в интерфейсе и отдельная панель) используются фрагменты  - для такого случая вполне возможно использовать отдельный класс-слушатель реализующий интерфейс `OnClickListener` и управляющий действиями по нажатиям  кнопок.
Вообще в плеере реализовано примерно таким образом: проигрывание музыки осуществляет `Service`. Так же создается фрагмент с интерфейсом управления проигрывателя, который взаимодействует с сервисом и управляет воспроизведением. Теперь везде, где требуется панель управления плеером, выводится этот фрагмент. При необходимости обмениваться данными с "внешним миром" создаются колбэки.

Если вам нужны реакции на действия пользователя в другой активити, создаете там собственный интерфейс и вешаете на него собственные слушатели. При необходимости передать параметры (например, номер проигрываемого трека), шлете [их интентом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556943/177345), через [колбэк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/293280/177345)(интерфейс обратного вызова) или библиотеки, [вроде EventBus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345). Для обратной связи [использовать метод `startActivityForResult()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/136267/177345)

Если вы задумались о необходимости действий в вашем вопросе, то вы, во первых, построили неправильно архитектуру своего приложения и во вторых, имеете недостаточно знаний для разработки под эту платформу. Рекомендую читать книги - Брайна Харди, Рето Майера и Пола Дейтела, потом писать приложение.

PS: 
передавать экземпляры активити куда бы то ни было худшая из возможных затей, рекомендую даже не думать об этом.

Comment: "PS: передавать экземпляры активити куда бы то ни было худшая из возможных затей, рекомендую даже не думать об этом." извиняюсь, но почему?.. недавно воспользовался передачей экземпляра активити в адаптер для динамического изменения состояния view активити. В коде это выразилось в 4-5 строчек. Работает вроде без сбоев. Мне понравилось данное решение. В чем могут быть косяки?

Comment: @ZigZag активити - класс, глубоко интегрированный в систему, работать с его экземплярами черевато всевозможными проблемами которые трудно предвидеть, гарантировано это утечки памяти, что еще вылезет, скажем при изменении состояния, трудно прогнозировать, нужно просто не делать так и все.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете реализовать статический класс-синглтон, который будет выступать в роли контроллера.

Активити 1 создалась и зарегистрировалась в контроллере.
Активити 2 создалась и зарегистрировалась в контроллере.
Активити 2 передала событие в контроллер.
Контроллер проверил существование Активити 1 и передал ей команду на выполнение действий.

Очень упрощённый пример:

Контроллер:

```
public class MainController {
    private static MainController mainController; //object

    private Activity[] listActivity = new Activity[2]; //list of activities


    private MainController() { // default constructor}

    public static MainController getInstance() { //create and return singleton
        if (mainController == null) {
            mainController = new MainController();
        }
        return mainController;
    }


    public void setActivity(Activity activity, int position) {
        listActivity[position] = activity; 
    }
}
```

В метод onCreate() активности добавляем

```
MainController controller = MainController.getInstance();
            controller.setActivity(this, 0); //for the first


MainController controller = MainController.getInstance();
            controller.setActivity(this, 1); // for the second
```

В метод onDestroy() добавлем

```
if (controller != null) controller.setActivity(null, 0); //remove registration for the first 

if (controller != null) controller.setActivity(null, 1); //remove registration for the second
```

Таким образом, если активность была убита, с ней ничего не случится. Иначе, контроллер берёт ссылку из своего массива активностей и передаёт ей команду. Например

```
if (controller[0] != null) {
                ((MainActivity) activity).doSomething(true);
            }
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!